# The maximum modulus principle for estimating

Tags: complex-analysis

" Let $f(z)$ be an entire function - analytic for all z in $\mathbb{C}$ and $|f(z)| \leq |e^{z}|$ on the contour $|z| = 1$. How the best large can $|f(\ln(2))|$ can be?". I used Cauchy's in equality and deduce that the large it can be $|f(\ln(2))| \leq e$. But my instructor's answer is 2 by appealing to maximum modulus principle. How can I apply Max. Modulus Principle to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** the function $g(z)=f(z)e^{-z}$ is an entire function with $|g|\leq 1$ for $|z|=1$.

Comment: If you apply Max. Mod Principle, then there exists a point $z_0$ on the boundary $|z| = 1$ that is the max of $g(z)$ i.e $|g(z)| \leq |g(z_0)| = |f(z_0) e^{-z_0}|$. I do not see how can this estimate $|f(\ln(2))|$ ?

Comment: @DongLe If $|g(z)|\leq 1$ on $|z|=1$, then $|g(z)|\leq1$ also in $|z|\leq 1$. Now, $\log(2)$ is in $|z|\leq 1$. Well, its real value satisfies that. I suppose the question was intended only for that value of $\log(2)$. Then $|g(\log(2))|\leq 1$.

Comment: I see what you are saying. Thank you very much!!!!